# Android Nexus 5.0 Crash Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 0x999e000c

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I get this error on the Lollipop 5.0 Nexus.

This is all i get

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 0x999e000c
```

I get this error when I am trying to record using AudioRecorder class of Android.

I used NDK Stack to dump the crash and I am getting the following logs.

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0/LRX21O/1570415:user/release-keys'
pid: 1752, tid: 2184, name: pool-15-thread-  >>> de.shopnow <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x9b6d2000
Stack frame #00 pc 00012f1c  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+95)
Stack frame #01 pc 000569b3  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioRecord::read(void*, unsigned int)+82)
Stack frame #02 pc 00095dbb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #03 pc 00270fd7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Need more logcat output.

Comment: Seriously. This is it. I cannot believe it either

Comment: I have run into a couple of these types of issues. Still hunting for the cause.

Comment: The native stacktrace should be available from the logcat as well, you may have filtered it out. Else can you share a piece of source code that helps reproducing this issue?

Comment: If I would be debugging this natively on unix-like system, I would recompile my app with debug info turned on, then attach a gdb to this process or start it in gdb, that way I'd get a full stack trace. If your app has some native code perhaps you should google on how to debug it with gdb or android alternative of it.

Comment: can't you run an ndk-stack command to see a dump?

Comment: Open your console, run adb logcat > someFile.txt, run your app, stop logging (ctrl+c in console), then open someFile.txt and search for "Fatal signal 11". Paste everything relevant that comes after it.

Comment: I have edited my question. does the new stacktrace help anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced and fixed this issue. This might be happening because of Hardware Acceleration. Go through this link for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks for your feedback. Will keep in mind going forward. :)